# /proc/scsi/<device> not found, but device is otherwise working

Tags: linux-mint, raid, proc, scsi

I have a *RocketRaid 622* RAID controller card, installed on a machine running Linux Mint 18.2.  The drivers have been successfully compiled and installed with `dkms`, after some customizations to make it compatible with the latest linux kernel.

One of the tools that comes with the card is a WebUI service.  It depends on the existence of the `/proc/scsi/rr62x` filesystem path, which appears to no longer exist in the latest Linux kernel?  The drives are mounted and visible, but the controller daemon just can't interact with the hardware, because it depends on this `/proc/scsi/rr62x` interface.

Is there a way to re-enable this missing interface on my machine?  Are there some good resources for why this interface was removed in newer versions of linux?

Comment: Some nodes are moved to the `/sys` filesystem. Look, e.g., in `/sys/block` (should contain device links) and `/sys/devices`. If you still need the `/proc/scsi` entry, you could add a `udev` rule to create a link.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I do see a single, matching name in "/sys/modules/rr62x".  Would that be identical to the previously-found "/proc/scsi/rr62x"?  I'd appreciate if you post this as an answer, with some details on how to set up a udev symlink rule in the /proc/scsi folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this simply doesn't work on newer versions of Ubuntu.  The `/proc/scsi` filesystem has changed in a way that no longer works with the outdated RAID management software.

I have two options:

- Set up on an older version of Ubuntu, likely one which is no longer supported.
- (Maybe, untested) possibly compile a custom kernel which adds support for the legacy `/proc/scsi` filesystem.
- Switch to Windows Server, which has functioning drivers and management software.

Using outdated, unsupported software is a non-option for me, as is trying to maintain a custom-built kernel which may or may not work.  I'm switching back to Windows for my server needs.